# Graph number of TRUE FALSE vs corresponding items

Tags: r

This might be a matter of not knowing what question to ask.

This is basically what I end up with so far (far from what I want).

```
a <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
b <- c("a", "b", "a", "b")
c <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))

qplot(b, a, data=c)
```

What I am trying to do is this:

Each item A or B has a TRUE or FALSE value associated with it. I want to graph the NUMBER of TRUE/FALSEs associated with each A or B.

My intuition was pointing in the direction of a for loop, e.g.,

```
for(1 to x)[if A == TRUE, A-COUNT += 1]
```

I could do this for B as well, and then simply create a new dataframe and graph with these produces numbers. However, my intuition is also saying that there is a simple function that could do this for me. Seems what I really want would a barplot with A and B on the x-axis and a count of TRUE/FALSE values on the y-axis.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your way of creating a data.frame is bad. `cbind` creates a matrix from two vectors. Since a matrix can hold only one data type, you get a character matrix. `data.frame` then turns this into a data.frame with two factor columns. TLDR: Ditch the `cbind`.

```
c <- data.frame(a, b)
```

Then you can aggregate within ggplot2 like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = c, aes(x = b, y = as.numeric(a))) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "point")
```

Or like this:

```
ggplot(data = c, aes(x = b, fill = a)) +
  stat_bin(geom = "bar", position = "stack")
```

Alternative, you can use `aggregate` (on one of the score of other functions that can split-apply-combine) to aggregate outside of ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks for the data.frame info. I seem to have skipped a lot of fundamental information and this helps a lot. Also, both of your solutions work perfectly. If you were to rephrase my original question, how would you have asked it? I'm still not sure of the terminology. Would I ask "how to split-apply-combine dataframe"?

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate` and staying close to what you've already done.

```
c$a <- as.logical(c$a)
z <- aggregate(. ~ b, c, sum)
qplot(x=z$b, y=z$a, geom="bar", stat="identity")
```